# how I can showing file app and java in android studio

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio, package

I have a problem in showing a file app and JAVA in Android Studio
And change Package name

I have installed JAVA but it is not showing

[image]

Comment: Are you using an android project or not?

Answer (score 0):

According to your screenshot, what you opened is not a android project. You should open your project File->Open. Then you can select the folder of your file application. If the folder contains an android project, there is an Android Studio logo next to it like this
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZnVK.png). This is an example of an [Android project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83u6B.png). Hope this help.

Comment: I have opened and want to change Package name ,But I did not find file java

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package

Comment: Go to src->main->java->[your package name] and you should find it.